Diff drive robot can not turn
I made a diff drive robot in the gazebo simulation, but it does not turn while moving forward. As seen in the video, although the right wheel rotates faster, the robot does not turn left. What could be the reason for this?
Video link: https://youtu.be/7JDV2pyG0qc
My main links in.urdf file:
<link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="0.8"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.01333" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.03538" iyz="0.0" izz="0.04333"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <geometry>  
            <box size="0.7 0.4 0.2"/> 
        </geometry>   
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.1" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/> 
        <material name="green"/>
    </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_wheel">
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="0.25"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0006771" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0006771" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00125"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
        <material name="black"/>     
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
    </collision>
</link>

<link name="right_wheel">
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="0.25"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0006771" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0006771" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00125"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
        <material name="black"/>     
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
    </collision>
</link>

<link name="caster_wheel">
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="0.25"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.00041665" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00041665" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00041665"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <geometry>
                <sphere radius="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <material name="black"/>            
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </collision>
</link>

